# Im trying to open a .csv file and read it as strings in an array in C programming

Tags: c, error-handling, computer-science

I am trying to read a .csv files which has a list of names in there. I have to read it as a string and put it into an array and then use insertion sort to sort the array. I am running into an error that says: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXSTRINGS 5000
int main(){
    char N[20];
        int i = 0;
        int z = 0;
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("NameList.csv", "r");
        while(fgets(N, 20, fp)!=NULL){
                z++;
        }
    char strings[MAXSTRINGS][20];
        rewind(fp);
        for(i=0;i<z && i < MAXSTRINGS;i++){
                fgets(N, 20, fp);
                strcpy(strings[i], N);
                printf("%N", N);
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Hardik. A tip from an old C programmer, to you keep on your wallet, _Always check your pointers!_ Opening a file may fail and if don't check it for NULL you will get in trouble when you try to use it

Comment: if the names in the .csv are not all exactly 19 characters long, then the reading of the values into an array will become out-of-step with the names.

Comment: the loop that is placing the names into an array will also have the spaces and commas from the .csv file.  Probably not what you want

Comment: They are not the same size. What would i put instead of 19 then.

Comment: suggest using `fgets()` to read a whole line from the .csv file into a large buffer in memory, then use `strtok()`  to separate each word.  Then use `strcpy()` to copy a word to the next available position in your array of words.  Suggest the 'delimiters' to use in the call to `strtok()` to be ","

Comment: Suggest your array of words be an array of struct, where the struct contains { char word[20]; }  and `realloc()` each time you need more room for more words

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that `*fp` is NULL due to an error on reading file.
If `*fp` is NULL, fgets return a segmentation fault.
Have you tried putting:

```
if(fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return(-1);
}
```

before the while loop?
Bye.